# Secure way to transmit data from one web app to another in user context

Tags: security, web, asp.net-core, interface, architecture

Our application is a Single Page App built with Angular and ASP.NET Core.
We have to integrate another web app which we will integrate in an iframe in our app. This app has to send data back to our application after the user finished his work.

I need to make sure, i can relate the data coming from this application to an authenticated user starting the operation in our app in a secure way.

Those were the options i thought in realizing the interface:

1. Generate a unique token in our application which knows about the related user and gets passed to the other application. The other application transmits this token along with it's other data back to our application and we can check this token on our backend to find out if it's a legitimate request and also relate it to a user.
2. Store cookies after authenticating the user in our app, so the other app could just post the data to our endpoint and the cookies make sure, the call takes place in the authenticated user's context. Also we would probably have to allow CORS from this site to make this work.
3. Use a non-http-based middleware (message broker) to connect the systems in a way, which keeps data transfer out of the browser.
4. Transmit the Bearer token from our application to the other application, so the other application can make an authenticated call to our application backend. 
   CORS would have to be activated as well for the other app's origin.
   However i'm a bit concerned about the security implications  this could have.

Which way would you suggest? Or would you suggest a completely other way of achieving the goal?

Thank you very much for any advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number 2 and 4 will both have potential security issues. Passing authentication contexts between different applications should be avoided, instead each application should be authenticated independently.

Number 3 would add complexity to your architecture while bringing little to no benefit for your use case - message brokers are not trivial to configure and operate. I would also question why two apps need to be integrated in the client via and iFrame but then are somehow able to share a message broker.

Number 1 for me is the cleanest option from your ideas. Consider however, you will need to pass this token somehow in the client which may open security holes. Think about the negative implications of what could happen, should a nefarious 3rd party get access to this token.

In your place I would question why an iFrame. Would it be possible for your app to provide the UI and instead communicate with this other application over an API?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! In order to secure the case where a malicious 3rd party get's access to the token, calls to API Backend should only be allowed for authorized users. So i would create a user account specific for this application which would authenticate itself on our API Backend and transmit the one-time-token along with the payload. 
iFrame is necessary because we need to display the UI of the application to be integrated. This is a monolithic application which has no budget to provide Rest APIs for us.